# conditional string aggregate .net

Tags: .net, string, aggregate

I have the following code

```
var definitionMap = definitions.Aggregate("", (current, next) => 
    current +  "[\\W\\s]" + 
    next.Tag.Replace("(", "\\(").Replace(")", "\\)") + "[\\W\\s]" + "|");
```

This works pretty well except I get a trailing | on the end, I could just remove this manually but is there anyway to stop the aggregate method from putting it there in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add it conditionally at the *start* of each term, i.e.

```
(current, next) => (current == "" ? "" : "|") + ...
```

However, I would also suggest you look at `StringBuilder` and a `foreach` loop here instead of `Aggregate`. Actually, since `StringBuilder` has a fluent API you can *actually* use it inside `Aggregate` - but I don't recommend it. Just because you *can* use a LINQ extension method doesn't mean it is automatically either *clearer* or *better*. In this case, it is neither IMO. In particular, at the moment you are generating a *lot* of unnecessary intermediate strings.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just go with `String.Join` and a `Select`?

```
var definitionMap =
    String.Join("|",
        definitions.Select(
            next =>
                "[\\W\\s]"
                + next.Tag.Replace("(", "\\(").Replace(")", "\\)")
                + "[\\W\\s]"));
```